# NDSolve 2 functions 2 variables with intermediate calculation : (1 time-space eq) + (1 space eq)

Tags: differential-equations, functions, system-variables

I have a system of differential equation with this structure :

$$\left\{\begin{split}&\partial_t n(t,r) + \nabla. \big(n(t,r)v(t,r)\big)=0 \\ & f\Big(n(t,r),v(t,r),\partial_r n(t,r),\partial_r v(t,r)\Big)=0\\ & n(0,r)=g(r)\\ \end{split}\right.$$
$$  $$

I'm writing it with NDSolve as follows :

```
R = 8
eta = 1
alpha = -1
nc = 2
K = 1
eps = 10^(-5)

sol =
 NDSolve[{D[n[t, r], t] + 1/r^2*D[r^2*v[t, r]*n[t, r], r] == 0, 
   n[eps, r] == (1 - Tanh[r - R])/2, 
   1/r^2*D[r^2*(4*eta/3*(D[v[t, r], r] - v[t, r]/r) + 
          2/3*alpha (n[t, r] - nc)), 
       r] + (4*eta/3*(D[v[t, r], r] - v[t, r]/r) + 
       2/3*alpha (n[t, r] - nc))/r == K/n[t, r]*D[n[t, r], r]}, {v[t, r], n[t, r]}, {t, eps, 10}, {r, eps, 10}];
```

But I get the errors :

> CoefficientArrays::poly: `-(2/3) (-2+n)-n$3018/n+4/3 (-(v/r)+v$3019)+(2 r (-(2/3) (-2+n)+4/3 (Times[<<3>>]+v$3019))+r^2 (-((2 n$3018)/3)+4/3 (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]+v$3021)))/r^2` is not a polynomial.
>
> NDSolve::femper: PDE parsing error of `{n$3020+(2 n r v+n$3018 r^2 v+n r^2 v$3019)/r^2,-(2/3) (-2+n)-n$3018/n+4/3 (-(v/r)+v$3019)+(2 r (-(2/3) (-2+n)+4/3 (Times[<<3>>]+v$3019))+r^2 (-((2 n$3018)/3)+4/3 (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]+v$3021)))/r^2}`. Inconsistent equation dimensions.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: you need to give *start and end* point of variables in NDSolve.like,`{v[t, r], n[t, r]}, {t,t_start,t_end},{r,r_start,r_end}`

Comment: Corrected thx, that was really stupid. But there are still errors

Comment: In v11.3 I got error about `dimension` of variable.
In v12.0 I got `Complex-Infinity` error.　I don't know the context/origin of this equation,but `what you typed ` is `the same` as the `text/paper you're reading`?

Comment: I have vs 11.3 the equation I derived myself the equation actually. But it's based on a paper. I just corrected a detail I miswrote on SE. But it's the same error... I think I didn't write that type of sytem of PDE rightly. I mean with 1 spatiotemporal+1 spatial equation.

Comment: There is a constraint the result has to respect : $v(t,0)=0$, but it doesn't matter to the errors if I write it explicitly or not.

Comment: ok! let's wait a little :). Someone will answer if the problem is NDSolve itself.

Comment: You are right I'm studying now the constraints I have to apply in order to solve the function $v$ at $t=0$. It's right that I'm missing something in the "physics" and the constraints of the problem.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to solve by method of lines but it was useless ... Good Luck!

Comment: Do you mean the equation in the question isn't correct at this point?

Comment: I have solved a similar set of coupled pdes via method of lines, should be possible to do.

Comment: @xzczd Yes I have to improve it I think. I think I'm going to close the question.